# merging entity with onetomany mapping and @version field causes delete of the previous mapping

Tags: jpa, version, one-to-many

Hi! All,

I have a mapping issue with two entities. mapped through a `@OneToMany` unidirectional relation. I have an entity `Artifact` which can have multiple `Revision`. Here's how I have mapped them

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "artifact")
public class Artifact implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 248298400283358441L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @Version
  private Integer version;

  ...   

  @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.REMOVE })
  @JoinTable(name = "artifact_revisions", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "artifact_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "revision_id"))
  private Set<Revision> revisions;
```

And the revisions entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "revision")
public class Revision implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -1823230375873326645L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  ...

  @Column(name = "date_created", nullable = false)
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  private Date creationDate;
```

The revision table saves the filed name that was updated; old value and new value etc.

The problem I face is that when I update the artifact; the last mapping gets deleted and then it inserts a new one, so if effect I only have the last but one revision available not the entire revision history.

```
Hibernate: 
    update
        artifact 
    set
        description=?,
        estimate=?,
        name=?,
        rank=?,
        status=?,
        sysId=?,
        version=? 
    where
        id=? 
        and version=?
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        artifact_revisions 
    where
        artifact_id=? 
        and revision_id=?
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        artifact_revisions
        (artifact_id, revision_id) 
    values
        (?, ?)
```

If I remove `@version` annotation from the artifact it works fine.

1. Is it because I am mapping the relation in a wrong manner? Should this relation be mapped as an element collection instead?
2. There is another Entity `Task` which is to be mapped with the `Revision` entity. So what will be the best approach here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not a straight answer to your question but I think you should look into hibernate envers. I think it's doing pretty similar thing. (envers stands for entity versioning). You just annotate entity with @Audited put some listeners into config and the rest magic is done for you.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I didn't understand much from your answer. Is this the default behavior and I have to override it using the @Audited annotations and listeners?

Comment: no it's not available by default, you'll have to add this lib to your classpath, start from here: http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/index.html#quickstart